# Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean]

Tags: spring, hibernate

**I have encounter a problem with spring hibernate, can some help me with this? I think I get all the library in my project:sping-orm ...**

> Jul 5, 2012 2:13:58 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4e3eca90: startup date [Thu Jul 05 14:13:58 EDT 2012]; root of context hierarchy
>   Jul 5, 2012 2:13:58 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
>   INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring.xml]
>   Jul 5, 2012 2:13:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
>   INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d576e70: defining beans [myDataSource,mySessionFactory,hibernateTemplate,expertiseDao]; root of factory hierarchy
>   Jul 5, 2012 2:13:59 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
>   INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@d576e70: defining beans [myDataSource,mySessionFactory,hibernateTemplate,expertiseDao]; root of factory hierarchy
>   Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean] for bean with name 'mySessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1262)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:576)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1331)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:897)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:566)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>       at com.gs.project1.main.TestRun.main(TestRun.java:17)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate.LocalSessionFactoryBean
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>       at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:257)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:417)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1283)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1254)
>       ... 9 more

[image]

Comment: Atleast you can mention the answer in comment. One should not leave the question as is.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the correct package name was not supplied. I did a quick search for the class LocalSessionFactoryBean and realized that its not available in the same package. Could be the difference in version of Spring framework with which this was built and the runtime library available.